# Raw Query inside query builder can secure for sql injection using laravel query builder?

Tags: php, laravel-5, postgresql-9.2

I would like to know when we use raw query inside query builder in laravel query builer as the following.

```
   $salesdata = DB::table('HEADER')
                ->join('BRANCH', 'HEADER.BRANCHCODE', '=', 'BRANCH.BRANCHCODE')
                ->select('HEADER.BRANCHCODE','BRANCH.BRANCHNAME',
                    DB::raw('SUM("HEADER"."AMT") as netamt'),
                    DB::raw('SUM("HEADER"."AMT") + SUM("HEADER"."DISCOUNT")- SUM("HEADER"."TAX1")- SUM("T_CASH_HEADER"."TAX2") as grossamt'),'BRANCH.BRANCHNAME',
                    DB::raw('SUM("HEADER"."COVER") as NetCover'),
                    DB::raw('SUM("HEADER"."DISCOUNT") as discount'),DB::raw('SUM("HEADER"."TAX1") as tax'),DB::raw('round(SUM("HEADER"."AMT")/SUM("HEADER"."COVER"),2) as avg'))
                ->whereBetween('HEADER.INVOICEDATE', [$fromDate, $toDate])
                ->groupBy('BRANCH.BRANCHCODE','BRANCH.BRANCHNAME','HEADER.BRANCHCODE')
                ->orderBy('AMT','ASC')
                ->get();
```

I would like to know above query can sure for sql injection using laravel.

Comment: you'd have to look at the laravel source code and see what it does with the variables you give it. Hopefully it parameterises them.

Answer (score 1):

No, you didn't pass any user input to your select statement except in `->whereBetween('HEADER.INVOICEDATE', [$fromDate, $toDate])` statement and this will use PDO parameter binding to prevent SQL injection. So, it is safe!

Comment: And if he also validates the strings using the DateTime class beforehand, he will know for sure that the input is safe